# Drop drow list dinámico JSP , AJAX, JQUERY O JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jsp

Re-formulando mi pregunta:

Como paso un valor que tomo de un `select` tag, o un `input` para entender el funcionamiento  y pasarlo a una variable JSP.

CODIGO JSP :

```
<body>
          <h1>Pasar ajax a jsp!</h1>
          <form method="POST">
               <input type="text" name="departamento" value="" />
               <input type="submit" value="aceptar" />
          </form>          
          <%
          String dp = "73";//Departamento del Tolima
          Servicios s = new Servicios( );                                                                      
          // Se instancia los recursos del modelo y se da respuesta al request                                                                             
          ResultSet droplst2 = s.consultarCiudades( 1 , dp );  //Ciudad por departamento opcion 1          
          %>
     </body>
```

Como recupero el valor del input `<input type="text" name="departamento" value="" />` y lo paso a la variable  `String dp = "73";` en lugar del "73" harcodeado .

Y poder ejecutar la consulta  de  `s.consultarCiudades( 1 , dp );`

Se que es por ajax, se que se puede utilizar jquery; pero llevo 2 días intentándolo y no logro hacer que me funcione.

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

drop list dinámico con JSP :

1)El `select` principal  debe tener `evento onchange`  -> `obtenerCiudades(this.value)`

```
<select name="txtDepartamento" onchange="obtenerCiudades(this.value)" >
    <%
        int num = 0;
     // Se instancia los recursos del modelo y se da respuesta al request 
        Servicios s = new Servicios( );
        ResultSet droplst = s.consultarDepartamento(num);
        //<![CDATA[
        if(droplst != null){                                                                                    
            while( droplst.next( ) )
            {
                if(droplst.getString( 2 ).equals("TOLIMA")){//Por defecto
                    out.println("<option value='"+ droplst.getString( 1 ) +"' selected>"+ droplst.getString( 2 ) +"</option>");
                }else{
                      out.println("<option value='"+ droplst.getString( 1 ) +"'>"+ droplst.getString( 2 ) +"</option>");
                } 
            }
        }
        //  ]]>
        droplst.close();
    %>                                                                           
</select></label>
```

Esto enviara el `selected` a la funcion y por ajax podremos hacer la busqueda del otro `select` dependiente.

Codigo script que permite recuperar el valor  y hacer la nueva busqueda:

```
 function obtenerCiudades(departamento) {
    $.ajax({
       url : "buscarCiudades.jsp?v_dp=" + departamento, /* se envia por GET */
       cache: false,
       dataType : 'html',
       success : function(datos) {
            $('#ciudad').html(datos);
       },
       error: function( ) { 
             $("#error").html("Se presento un problema, Departamento No =" + departamento);
         } 
    });

}
```

Este re-direcciona el `selected`  al JSP donde se creara el `select` dependiente **En este JSP solo debe ir el código a retornar**

buscarCiudades.jsp

```
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="modelo.Servicios"%>

   <select name="txtCiudades" onchange="">
      <% 
         String dp = request.getParameter("v_dp");//Departamento del Tolima
         Servicios s = new Servicios( );
          // Se instancia los recursos del modelo y se da respuesta al request                                                                             
          ResultSet droplst2 = s.consultarCiudades( 1 , dp );  //Ciudad por departamento opcion 1
          //<![CDATA[
          if(droplst2 != null){                                                                                    
              while( droplst2.next( ) )
              {                                                                                   
                                              //Numero Ciudad       //Nombre Ciudad
               out.println("<option value='"+ droplst2.getString( 1 ) +"'>"+ droplst2.getString( 2 ) +"</option>");
              } 
          } 
          //  ]]>
          droplst2.close();
      %>                                                                          
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para los lenguajes que se ejecutan del lado del servidor para formar los tag al cliente/visitante (y este último lo reciba), te tengo dos sugerencia y claro aplica solo una según actualmente te ea más pronta realzar:

**Reenviar y armar**

Para esto el escenario es que dentro de un `form` coloques aquellos elementos que mantendrás; por ejemplo en este caso solo País:

```
<!-- Obtienes los parámetros del submit al form -->

<!-- Obtienes las ciudades conforme al Pais seleccionado -->

<form action="_self" method="[GET o POST según tu flujo de datos]" id="miForm">
   <select id="pais" name="pais" onchange="$('#miForm').submit()" >
    <!-- 
       Poblando el select
       No olvides obtener el elemento que quedo seleccionado y establecerlo como seleccionado
     -->
   </select>
</form>
<!-- lo coloco fuera por de momento desconocer la estructura -->
<select id="ciudad" name="ciudad" >
  <!-- Poblando el select con las ciudades -->
</select>
```

coloque `_self` para indicar que es el mismo jsp que se volvera a llamar que es lo mismo que no indicarlo.

**Ajax**

Esto puede ser de dos formas que recibas objetos con *value* y *texto* (valor o identificador de cada cíudad y Descripcion/nombre de la ciudad respectivamente) o que te devuelva el tag `Select` armado; por simplicidad te comentare como este último:

*En el script*

```
function obtenerCiudades(pais) {
   $.ajax({
      url : "rutayNombreFormadoSelect.js?idpais=" + pais,
      cache: false,
      dataType : 'html',
      success : function(datos) {
            $('#elSelectCiudad').html(datos);
      },
      error: function(....) { } <!-- aqui tu manejo en caso de error ver documentación respectiva
   });
}
```

*En tu html*

```
<select id="pais" name="pais" onchange="obtenerCiudades(this.value)" >
   <!-- 
      Poblando el select
      No olvides obtener el elemento que quedo seleccionado y establecerlo como seleccionado
   -->
</select>

<span id="elSelectCiudad"> <!-- según requieras o tu CSS puede ser un DIV, SPAN o según requieras; este será el contenedor
 <!-- Aqui se colocara el tag formado en la petición ajax al llamar [...].html() en success -->
</span>
```

## EDITADO

JSP lo use poco; espero lo siguiente te sea ilustrativo a lo que tienes que realizar, disculpa si equivoco las instrucciones precisas pero pondré líneas de comentario para indicar lo que corresponde.

**Tu JSP a llamar usar por AJAX**

Le llamaremos `obtenerCiudades.jsp`. Este tendrá como función devolver el TAG select formado:

```
<%
// Los imports y encabezados necesarios

String idPais = request.getParameter("pais"); // Aquí según corresponda si indicaste que se envie por GET o POST

// Realizas tu consulta para obtener las ciudades de ese país; 
// a continuación ciclo asumiendo que se obtuvo como se muestra aqui la variable "rs1"
%>
<select id="colocaelID" name="mismoqueID" [class y demas atributos que necesites]>
<% while(rs1.next()) { %>
    <option value="<%=rs1.getString(posQueIndicaelIdentificador)%>"><%=rs1.getString(posQueIndicalaDescripcion)%></option>
<% } %>
</select>    
<!-- Solo se regresa el select armado, nada más, 
  ninguna otra etiqueta html saldo desees un label de descripción -->
```

Consideraciones del fragmento anterior

- Como asumo el tipo de datos que tiene la [variable rs1](https://blog.udemy.com/jsp-ajax/); *solo como se llego hasta colocar los datos en la misma no su uso*.

**Invocando a `obtenerCiudades.jsp`**

Para usarla sería lo siguiente:

```
function obtenerCiudades(pais) {
    $.ajax({
       url : "obtenerCiudades.jsp?pais=" + pais, /* se envia por GET */
       cache: false,
       dataType : 'html',
       success : function(datos) {
             $('#elSelectCiudad').html(datos);
       },
       error: function(....) { } /* aqui tu manejo en caso de error ver documentación respectiva */
    });
}
```

**Nota:** Anteponer a obtenerCiudades.jsp la ruta que corresponda según donde lo tenga ubicado en tu proyecto.

## EDITADO ERROR

He intentado la forma que me planteas y así queda mi código `ajax`:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
              function obtenerCiudades(pais) {
                    $.ajax({
                       url : "agregarZona.jsp?pais=" + pais, /* se envia por GET */
                       cache: false,
                       dataType : 'html',
                       success : function(datos) {
                            $('#ciudad').html(datos);
                       },
                       error: function( ) { 
                             $("#error").html("error" + pais);
                         } 
                    });
                }           
        </script>
```

Intente poniendo en la URL la misma pagina donde invoco la función así podría utilizar el `request` directamente.

Funciona! Pero con errores.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

a que se debe este error?

Mi código `JSP` sigue igual

```
    <select name="txtDepartamento" onchange="obtenerCiudades(this.value)" >
    <%
        int num = 0;
     // Se instancia los recursos del modelo y se da respuesta al request 
        Servicios s = new Servicios( );
        ResultSet droplst = s.consultarDepartamento(num);
        //<![CDATA[
        if(droplst != null){                                                                                    
            while( droplst.next( ) )
            {
                if(droplst.getString( 2 ).equals("TOLIMA")){//Por defecto
                    out.println("<option value='"+ droplst.getString( 1 ) +"' selected>"+ droplst.getString( 2 ) +"</option>");
                }else{
                      out.println("<option value='"+ droplst.getString( 1 ) +"'>"+ droplst.getString( 2 ) +"</option>");
                } 
            }
        }
        //  ]]>
        droplst.close();
    %>                                                                           
</select></label>
<label><span class="text-form2">Ciudad:</span>
    <select name="txtCiudades" onchange="">
    <% 
        String dp = request.getParameter("pais");//Departamento del Tolima

        // Se instancia los recursos del modelo y se da respuesta al request                                                                             
        ResultSet droplst2 = s.consultarCiudades( 1 , dp );  //Ciudad por departamento opcion 1
        //<![CDATA[
        if(droplst2 != null){                                                                                    
            while( droplst2.next( ) )
            {                                                                                   
                                            //Numero Ciudad       //Nombre Ciudad
             out.println("<option value='"+ droplst2.getString( 1 ) +"'>"+ droplst2.getString( 2 ) +"</option>");
            } 
        } 
        //  ]]>
        droplst2.close();
    %>                                                                           
</select></label>
```

Comment: He  intentado lo que me comentas .... pero no logro hacer que funcione, podrías darme un ejemplo pequeño .? @Roberto

Comment: Intente la modificación que se me plantea y se me presenta un error ... podrías decirme que hice mal ? @Roberto

Comment: Como veo mantienes tu estructura iniciar entonces estas optando por actualizar la pagina; para ello deberas usar <form> y dentro de esta colocar los elementos que tienes (los selects) y realizar el submit cuando cambie el que define la segunda lista. Suerte.